# Storm door closer with timer

Tags: storm-door, closer

Is there a storm door closer product with a timer function? i.e once opened it should stay there for set amount of time before closing. This is really helpful so that door doesn't slam on your back when you are entering slowly(say you are carrying something into the house).

Comment: you can tighten the speed adjustment screw so that the door takes, say 30 seconds to fully close, which will stop slams. you might need to re-align and oil the latch; it has to be perfect if there's no momentum when the door finally closes all the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can usually be adjusted to close more slowly; fancier (and more expensive) ones (two stage) can close slowly, then faster at some point, but other than electrified/automated (think handicap access button and **much** more expensive) I don't think you'll find any that just wait, fully open.

Most basic closers include a stop to hold the door open, if you are carrying something into the house - that needs to be manually set and released. Some commercial (fancier and more expensive) closers include an easier "hold-open" where you just push the door a bit further than usual and a spring-loaded detent holds it until you pull it closed. In both cases you'll need to go back and close the door when you are done needing it open.

Comment: Many commercial closers have _three_ arc stages.